# App_Data Visual 2013 MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, app-data

I have got a problem with adding App_Data folder in MVC4 project.
I don't know why this option is not available. I have got MS SQL Server 2014 and Visual 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your Web Application and select `Add` -> `Add ASP.NET Folder` -> `App_Data`

[image]

Or just add it as a standard folder.

Comment: I tried like this, still I don't have access for this option...
Normal folder is not this same. App_Date have specific rules

Comment: Then just add it as a normal folder. It's absolutely the same. There's no difference.

Comment: App_Data is a 
special directory in ASP.NET which already has the correct security access permissions for database access.

Comment: Yes, it's special from ASP.NET perspective, but it's not special at all in terms of Windows directory. I don't know why this option wouldn't be available to you in VS (one thing that comes to mind is because you don't have an ASP.NET project), but I assure you that you can add it as an absolutely standard folder. Because of its name, it will be treated specifically by ASP.NET.

Comment: Oki will add normal folder and we will see what application will say me.
Thanks for your time.